# RAILS S3 displaying pdf file stored in amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

How to display pdf file which is stored in s3 amazon in rails application???

Answer (score 0):

when uploading files to S3 the filename has to have **No Spaces or special caracters**.
To upload files with spaces use the following

*yourmodel.rb*

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :video,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_video_file_name",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_video_file_name" 

  Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_video_file_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.normalized_video_file_name
  end

  def normalized_video_file_name
    "#{self.id}-#{self.video_file_name.gsub( /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]/, '_')}" 
  end
end
```

What are we doing here? Easy, in has_attached_file we edit the way paperclip returns the path and url by default, the most relevant components when saving and loading the file in order to display it. Paperclip default values are:

```
path default => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename" 
url default => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

Values preceded by ’:’ are the standard interpolations paperclip has
http://blog.wyeworks.com/2009/7/13/paperclip-file-rename

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an :s3_headers entry to your has_attachment line:

```
has_attached_file :asset,
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
:path => "uploads/:id/:basename.:extension",
:s3_headers => {"Content-Disposition" => "attachment"},
:s3_permissions => 'authenticated-read',
:s3_protocol => "http",
:bucket => "my_bucket_or_something"
```